# How do I find the cut point value used by the lda( ) function in MASS package for R?

Tags: r

I am working with the `MASS` package in `R`, specifically the `lda()` function. I would like to know *how to get R to return the threshold value* of `LD1` (i.e. the cut point or cutoff) that the `lda` function uses to determine which group or class each sample should be assigned to.

I know that R does not just use the midpoint average between the two group means for `LD1`. I need to know the cut point value so that I can run multiple iterations of `lda` and reallocate the misclassified samples prior to each new iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to depend on the data unless you force it otherwise. `?lda` produces:

```
prior   
the prior probabilities of class membership. If unspecified, the class proportions for 
the training set are used. If present, the probabilities should be specified in the 
order of the factor levels.
```

If you want to see the code or generate a prediction look either at `predict.lda` or read further in `?predict.lda` and in the MASS book. `predict.lda` also offers a handle on specifying the cutpoint:

```
prior   
The prior probabilities of the classes, by default the proportions in the training set
 or what was set in the call to lda.
```